# I disabled the USB 3.0 ports and now can't use my mouse or keyboard

Tags: windows, bios

I stupidly disabled the USB 3.0 ports in [Device Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager), thinking I was doing something else. Now neither my mouse nor keyboard works. It boots up fine, but I don’t have any mouse or keyboard to enter the password.

If I reset the BIOS to factory defaults, will that fix it?

Comment: @Steve, if it is a desktop, there must be a PS/2 mouse & keyboard interface which you can use provided you have a PS/2 keyboard & mouse

Comment: Is the keyboard and mouse really USB3? With blue connectors? I expect the USB2 in the same physical jack to still work, since it is a separate device wit a different driver.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this unit is an Intel NUC. There are 4 USB ports, the ones on the back have never worked.

Answer (score 4):

Do you still have USB 2 anywhere? HID (Human Interface Devices), such as keyboards and mice, should go in USB 2 ports if available.

You can also try booting your Windows (I assume it's Windows based on 'Device Manager') in Safe Mode. This will usually load basic USB 2.0 drivers, and you should be able to undo your changes this way.

Resetting the BIOS will not affect Device Manager inside of Windows.